# Unable to order the bar plot in R

Tags: r

Can someone shed some light on how to order the following bar plot:

```
day<-c('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thur','Fri','Sat')
value<-c(13,100,45,32,56,78,65)

df<-data.frame(day,value)
df<-df[order(value),]


ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=tot, x=day,fill=day), stat="identity")+
  labs(title=paste( "bar plot")) +ylab("y")+xlab("x")+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

day<-factor(c('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thur','Fri','Sat'),
            levels = c('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thur','Fri','Sat'),
            ordered = T)
value<-c(13,100,45,32,56,78,65)

df<-data.frame(day,value)

#By day
ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=value, x=day,fill=day), stat="identity")+
  labs(title=paste( "bar plot")) +ylab("y")+xlab("x")+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

```
#By value
ggplot(df,aes(y=value, x=reorder(day,value),fill=day)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  labs(title=paste( "bar plot")) +ylab("y")+xlab("x")+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]